# error: cannot find symbol method AnimatorListener

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a background that loops forever with the help of the property Animation API. However, I get the following error.

```
Error:(106, 19) error: cannot find symbol method AnimatorListener(<anonymous AnimationListener>)
```

Here is my code:

```
ImageView ground = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ground);
ImageView ground2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ground2);
AnimatorSet moveGround = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.ground_move);
AnimatorSet moveGround2 = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.ground_move2);

moveGround.setTarget(ground);
moveGround2.setTarget(ground2);
moveGround.start();

moveGround.AnimatorListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    // Start background 2
    moveGround2.start();
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `moveGround` as an `AnimationSet`.  The `AnimationSet` class does not define or inherit a method called `AnimatorListener`; see the [javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html).  (For a start, it would be an egregious Java style violation to define a method whose name started with an upper-case letter !!!)

However, it does declare a method called [`addListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html#addListener(android.animation.Animator.AnimatorListener)) ... and I think that is what you should be calling at the point you are getting the compilation error; e.g.

```
  moveGround.addListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
      ....
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set an instance of a class inside of a method that does not exist for a class without using a method.

You're doing this:

```
moveGround.AnimatorListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }
```

And if an Animatorset even had a setAnimatorListener () method you would do something like this:

```
moveGround.setAnimatorListener(new AnimationListener() {
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}
```

Comment: Close ... but not correct.  There is no `setAnimatorListener` method either.

Comment: Thank you @StephenC couldn't remember the exact methods offhand